# Override parents z-index in child

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a part of DOM like this

```
<div class="parent">
   <a class="link">Link me </a>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.parent {
   z-index: -2;
}
.link {
 z-index:9999;
}
```

I want a part of "parent" to wrap overlap/wrap under the previous div. So, I am using z-index -2. No matter what z-index I use for link, its not clickable. Any suggestions.

PS: I cant use larger z-index for parent's predecessor div. Because "parent" has 3 siblings (columns) that do not need to go under the predecessor.

Comment: Do you forget href attribute ?

Comment: I think `z-index` is relative to the parent element and not to the body (Assuming both element's has `position:relative/absolute`)

Comment: And as @ndufreche pointed out - If you don't have an `href` attribute then the cursor will not become a pointer when you hover it. You can add it form the CSS (`cursor: pointer;`) but I'm pretty sure the snippet in your question is not the full  version of your code

Comment: I have it. I missed it while it typing it out here on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the parent/child relationship. I f the parent is behind another element, also its child will be.

But you can add `pointer-events: none` to the previous (to be overlapped) DIV if it doesn't contain any links itself. This will allow to "click through it".

Note: IF the previous DIV contain links, that won't work, since those links won't work anymore.